# Will quad-core AMD A6-3410MX 1.6 GHz (32-bit) run ubuntu 20.04? (and i have 6 GB ram)

Tags: 32-bit

I have laptop with this processor and i have 6 GB of ram + many space but my machine is AMD64 but i need version that can run on AMD A6-3410MX (When i check architecture it show Llano)

Comment: Llano is the codename, not the arch.  this is an x86 64-bit processor which AMD64 will work for.  (A Google search for that CPU yields the information quickly).  Note though that "Will ubuntu run on my system?" is an opinion based question and we instead suggest you boot a live usb or such to actually test and see if it works in the live session for you.

Comment: @thomas-ward Thanks for info

Comment: Note I turned this into an answer for you.  Since it directly hits that your system is an `amd64` aka `x86_64` processor with the evidence, you might want to accept it as an answer if it properly answers for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting "Architecture".  Llano is the **codename** of the series of processor.  It is *not* the actual architecture.

Googling the CPU you have yields useful information (from sites such as [this one](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-A-Series-A6-3410MX-Notebook-Processor.55754.0.html)).  The two things you have to look for in data such as this are the following:

1. What's the architecture?  (x86 means standard processors that are AMD/Intel, and not special chips like ARM chips)
2. Does it have 64-bit support?  If yes and arch is x86 then x86_64 is the architecture of the system (aka amd64).

The freehand red circle shows the critical bits of info here from the above-linked site.

[image]

**Your system is an `amd64` architecture system, so the standard Ubuntu 64-bit will be sufficient to match your architecture.**